# How to trim all leading/trailing <br> code using php

Tags: php, html, trim

I am trying to remove all leading and trailing `<br>` in a string using PHP.

Here is an example

```
<br><br>
Hello<br>
World<br>
<p>This is a message<br>...</p>
<br><br><br><br>
```

I want to return

```
Hello<br>
World<br>
<p>This is a message<br>...</p>
```

I tried to do the following

```
echo trim($str, '<br>');
```

But it does not remove them. How can I remove the new line html code?

Comment: I don't want to replace all of them. only the starting and the ending

Comment: It's weird, `echo trim($str, '<br>');` seems to be working just fine for me using your example string.

Comment: Maybe there is another character there interfering with things. Maybe it would work If you included the default trimmed characters as well? `echo trim($str, "<br> \t\n\r\0\x0B");`

Comment: @Don'tPanic try to execute this code and see what you get  `$message = '<br><br>
<div>Hello<br>
World<br>
<p>This is a message<br>...</p>
<br><br><br><br>
 <blockquote type="cite"><br>
 <div><br></div>
 </blockquote>';
 
$message = trim($message, "<br> \t\n\r\0\x0B");`  it seems to be removing the first `<` and the last `>`

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense that it would do that. The character mask in trim just specifies a list of characters. Trim will remove all characters in the character mask from the beginning and end of the string, regardless of order, until it encounters a character not included in the character mask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` with the beginning `^` and end `$` anchors:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^(<br>){0,}|(<br>){0,}$/', '', $string);
```

Or for multiple lines:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^(<br>){0,}|(<br>){0,}$/m', '', $string);
```

You could also `trim()` it multiple times:

```
while($string !== ($string = trim($string, '<br>'))){}
```

Comment: it is not working. Perhaps it is something I am doing wrong here is my code  `$msg = '<br><br>
Hello<br>
World<br>
<p>This is a message<br>...</p>
<br><br><br><br>';
   
   echo preg_replace('/^<br>|<br>$/', '', $msg);`

Comment: Pattern should be like this: `"/^(<br>){0,}|(<br>){0,}$/"` . With your pattern, it will remove only first and last `<br>`. Also, it will work with a string without `\r\n`. You might need to remove line endings before trimming or add `.../m` to trim each line

Comment: Added a non-regex alternate.

Answer (score 1):

This function does the job. Also applicable to anything else really.

```
//remove all leading and trailing occurences of needle ($n) from haystack ($h)
function trimAll($h, $n){
    if(!$h = trim($h,$n)){ 
        trimAll($h, $n);
    }
    return $h;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function that will do the job a little better as it gives me more flexibility on what characters to remove and when this function by default will first remove the leading/trailing characters in order:

1. any tabs
2. any new lines
3. any
4. any
5. any tabs
6. any new lines

---

```
function trimString($str, $myList = array("\t","\n", "<br>","<br />", "\t","\n") ){
    if( ! is_array($myList) ){
        $charsToTrim[] = $chr;
    } else {
        $charsToTrim = $myList;
    }

    foreach($charsToTrim as $chr){
        $len = strlen($chr);
        $nlen = $len * -1;

        while( substr($str, 0, $len) == $chr){
            $str = trim(substr($str, $len));
        }

        while( substr($str, $nlen) == $chr){
            $str = trim(substr($str, 0, $nlen));
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

to use

```
// default use case    
echo trimString($message);
```

or

```
//remove only one string
echo trimString($message, '<br>');  // remove only the leading training '<br>'
```

or

```
//remove more than 1 string in order
echo trimString($message, array('<br>'<br />') );
```

I hope this helps someone out there :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$p=array(
  '<br><br>',
  'Hello<br>',
  'World<br>',
  '<p>This is a message<br>...</p>',
  '<br><br><br><br>'
);
function trimdeluxe($str, $sub)
{
    $parts=explode($sub, $str);
    for ($x=0; $x<2; $x++) {
            foreach ($parts as $i=>$v) {
                    if (!strlen($v)) {
                            unset($parts[$i]);
                    } else {
                            break;
                    }
            }
            $parts=array_reverse($parts);
    }
    return implode($sub,$parts);
}

foreach ($p as $str) {
    print $str . ' -> ' . trimdeluxe($str, '<br>') . "\n";
}
```

Comment: You win on terseness - I did it this way because regexes are hard to maintain (and to get get right first time?)