# remove leading and trailing break tags from string

Tags: php, regex

I have developed a simple **PHP** feed system which displays all of the logged in users posts. It works fine, however, I have come across a *"bug"* where if the user has made a status which contains leading and/or trailing `<br>` points, it'll break the status view.

Now, before anyone marks this as a duplicate; If have tried the following approaches (and two more from posts which I can no longer find) in removing the trailing and leading `<br>`'s:

1. [Remove `<br>`'s from the end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618082/remove-brs-from-the-end-of-a-string)
2. [How to trim all leading/trailing 
    code using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954626/how-to-trim-all-leading-trailing-br-code-using-php)

However, they **a)** do nothing at all, or **b)** do work, but remove all the `<br>` points within the string, even if they are in the middle.

Attempts:

```
$ctx = preg_replace('/^(<br>){0,}|(<br>){0,}$/m', '', nl2br(escape($post->ctx)));
```

---

```
$ctx = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', nl2br(escape($post->ctx)));
```

---

```
$ctx = preg_replace('#(( ){0,}<br( {0,})(/{0,1})>){1,}$#i', '', nl2br(escape($post->ctx)));
```

---

I have been working on this for a little while now, but have come up with no *proper* fix. I have come close with **attempt c**, however, it would remove **all** `<br>` points.

All help is appreciated, 
Thanks!

Comment: @Deadooshka `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '�'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace with contents optionally wrapped by the `<br />`'s (note that `nl2br` inserts `<br />`):

```
^(?:<br />[\n\r]+)*(.*?)(?:<br />[\n\r]+)*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7KDCuA/3

And the PHP code:

```
$input = "\nHello World\nhello world\n\n";
$unwrapped = preg_replace("|^(?:<br />[\n\r]+)*(.*?)(?:<br />[\n\r]+)*$|s", '$1', nl2br($input));
echo $unwrapped;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/BT0A5583

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this! :)

Comment: I get the error `Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '^'`

Comment: Ah yes, I no longer get the error. However, the problem still occurs. Does it help to know that the new lines aren't in the string until I use `nl2br` on them?

Comment: Yes, the `nl2br` should be applied to the `$input` first.

Comment: I've done that, like so: `$ctx = preg_replace('/^(?:<br>)*(.*?)(?:<br>)*$/', '$1', $nl2br(escape($post->ctx)));`. But, it doesn't work :/

Comment: All right, I see. The problem is that `nl2br` replaces every newline with `"<br />\n"` and not simply `"<br>"`. So the tag should be adjusted. The `/s` modifier should also be added to match newlines as ordinary characters.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this in a moment :)

Comment: It still doesn't want to work, no matter what I do :/

Comment: I've just updated with possible `\n` and `\r` taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

sounds to me like this should already help:

```
nl2br(escape(trim($post->ctx)));
```

This will work, if the users aren't allowed to enter html for their status. The trim will remove all whitespaces at the beginning and the end of the string and so the string passed to nl2br has no line breaks at the beginning and at the end.